# Border in CSS display-table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want to add a border before my last row and can't find a way without breaking my design. Every input or suggestions are appreciated.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44odhjkv/)

```
see jsfiddle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `<div class="tt-entry-hr"></div>` outside of the span.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44odhjkv/1/)

Comment: ok thx, it worked. Additionally i added a block-element inside a inline-element. Now its a span too. :)

Comment: Awesome, good deal. I wasn't sure if you wanted that to be a span also so I left as is. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS: And delete that -hr div.

```
.tt-container > .tt-entry-row:last-child > .tt-entry {
  border-top:thin solid white;
}
```

Adjust to suit.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44odhjkv/3/)

Comment: @Alex you really should look at this possible solution, too. It works via pure CSS and you don't need to add that -hr span (or div) to your html. Makes the html (and any code that generates it) much simpler.

Comment: hm, its no pure CSS-solution. You added an empty tt-entry-element. But i guess, its a cleaner solution than add a .tt-entry-hr-element